# Checking for a space in a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and as part of an assignment I have to create a connect 4 game. I have the valid_moves part of this function, but I am not sure how to check if where an opponents disc is and how I should place my disc in a position which avoids the opponent from winning, but providing me with the advantage of winning. Here is the code:

```
def ai_player(board, turn, valid_moves):
"""
Inputs:
    board: numpy array of the disks for each player, e.g.
            [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

            - 0 empty locations
            - 1 your disks
            - 2 your opponents disks
    turn: integer turn counter (starts from 1)
    valid_moves: numpy array of valid col index numbers where a disk can be
                 placed, e.g. [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Return:
    col index number --> an integer number of the col where you want to
                         place a disk e.g. 0 (NB: this return value must
                         appear in the valid_moves array)
"""

colIndex = range(10)

for i in range(len(valid_moves) - 1):
    if turn == 1:
        ind = colIndex[4]

    elif turn > 1 and (len(valid_moves) > 0):
        if valid_moves[colIndex[i] + 1] == 0 and colIndex[i] < 10:
            ind += 1

        elif valid_moves[colIndex[i] - 1] == 0:
            ind -= 1
    else:
        # choose a random move to make from the valid_moves list
         ind = random.randint(0, len(valid_moves)-1)



#This is my code to add my coin (1) at an empty position and after the opponents coin (2)
for j in range(len(valid_moves) - 1):

    if(colIndex[i] == 2):
        colIndex[i + 1] = 1
    elif colIndex[i] == 0 and colIndex[i] == 1 and colIndex[i] != 2:
        colIndex[i + 1] = 1

return valid_moves[ind]
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this is really too broad a question, but as a naive first approach, I'd check every possible position for a column of 4, every position for a row of 4 and every position for a diagonal of 4. If you find 3 of your colour with the other space being a gap, check if you can place a token in the gap and if you can make that move. If you don't find any winning moves, repeat looking for places your opponent may win that you can block. If you still don't find a move, then place a token randomly (and then think about how to improve this step)

Comment: I'd also consider modelling my board as stacks of tokens instead of a 2 dimensional array, it'll simplify adding tokens and not make the search much harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an **AI problem** rather than a Python one. I'm unsure whether you are familiar with the term ***heuristics*** applied to the field of computer science but imagine this situation: you start the game and you want to make a move. To automatically plan your move (and to make a ***meaningful*** move that could make you win the game) you would need to consider the oponent's possibilities after you make your move.

To do this, you could try **listing all possible moves and assign a "score"** (a numerical value) **to those moves depending on how good they are**. Example: a move that makes you win the game has to have the maximum score.

From a over-simplified point of view, the concept of *heuristics* is to assign a "score" to the possible actions to decide which move is the one you, or the machine, want to make. ***To code a good strategy to winning is to code several good and meaningful strategies*** and putting them all together.

How to decide on the strategies? You could think of several game situations and to determine which action is better. You could ask yourself the following questions:

- Which move is better, to accumulate all disks in an area or to disperse the disks? If you think dispersing the disks is better you could give a better "score" for the move.
- Is it better to put a disk on a slot if there are three disks of the oponent or not? Obviously yes, as otherwise the machine would win.

If you consider several heuristics, ***you could automatically determine which is the best possible move given the board and a simulation of the X following moves*** (to avoid making the problem [computationally unsolvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory)). I'm sure you can find some other examples on several academic webpages, and you could find examples of heuristics even googling "connect 4 heuristics".

**Edit:** actually, I just found a [webpage](http://roadtolarissa.com/connect-4-ai-how-it-works/) explaining possible applicable heuristics.